# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rotateOnAxis') error occurred

Tags: javascript, three.js

The cube.obj file and the cube.mtl file downloaded from three.js can be rotated well. By the way, the capsule.obj file and capsule.mtl file I made by Adobe Dimension are well loaded, but when I try to rotate it, the error appears as shown in the following snapshot. What did I do wrong and the file I made myself can't be rotated and an error appears?

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgqxu.png)

[cube.obj](https://github.com/goodcontext/questions/blob/52e8fe63baebb33213d7229ea5840d34f4b2ffac/cube.obj)
[cube.mtl](https://github.com/goodcontext/questions/blob/52e8fe63baebb33213d7229ea5840d34f4b2ffac/cube.mtl)
[capsule.obj](https://github.com/goodcontext/questions/blob/52e8fe63baebb33213d7229ea5840d34f4b2ffac/capsule.obj)
[capsule.mtl](https://github.com/goodcontext/questions/blob/52e8fe63baebb33213d7229ea5840d34f4b2ffac/capsule.mtl)

app.js

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/MTLLoader.js'
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

import styleCSS from '../styles/style.css';
import image from '../images/shutterstock_2184208287.jpg';
import capsuleObj from '../object/capsule.obj';
import capsuleMtl from '../object/capsule.mtl';

const RAD = .005;

let camera, scene, renderer, object;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 20);
    camera.position.z = 2.5;

    // scene

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 15);
    camera.add(pointLight);
    scene.add(camera);

    // model

    const onProgress = function (xhr) {

        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {

            const percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');

        }

    };

    new MTLLoader()
        .setPath('.')
        .load(capsuleMtl, function (materials) {
            materials.preload();

            new OBJLoader()
                .setMaterials(materials)
                .setPath('.')
                .load(capsuleObj, function (obj) {
                    object = obj;
                    object.position.y = - 0.95;
                    object.scale.setScalar(.05);
                    scene.add(object);

                }, onProgress);

        });

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.useLegacyLights = false;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.minDistance = 2;
    controls.maxDistance = 5;

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
    const axis = new THREE.Vector3(.5, .5, 0);
    object.rotateOnAxis(axis, RAD);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: No. I want the object to rotate. So I wrote object. The cube.obj rotates properly. But the capsule.obj that I made has an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` is set only after the MTL file is loaded, which happens asynchronously. Therefore, you must check whether `object` is set:

```js
if (object) {
    object.rotateOnAxis(axis, RAD);
}
```

Comment: @goodcontext The comment section is not intended to ask follow-up questions. If you have a new question, please [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @goodcontext What do you mean with "gone"? Was it transparent before and is opaque now, or was it never transparent? What about `material.transparent = true;`?